# Expected value of high fives on a chessboard

Tags: expected-value

> 64 people are standing on an 8x8 chessboard, facing randomly chosen neighbours. If two people are facing each other, they will give each other a high five. On average, how many high fives can we expect to see?

Source: [puzzledquant.com](https://www.puzzledquant.com/problems/cllnyeqvq0000ml086cb4qvms)

My approach: We divide the chessboard into $3$ groups, based on number of neighbours. If we place indicator variable on each square, for the middle $6$x$6$ = $36$ squares, we have $1/4$ * $1/4$ if the $2$ people face each other and this can happen in $4$ ways (for the $4$ neighbours) hence total we have $1/16$ * $4$ * $36$, similarly for corner squares we have $1/16$ * $2$ * $4$ and for the remaining we have $1/16$ * $3$ * $24$. However, the summation of these 3 don't match the answer of $335/36$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not focus on squares but on edges that separate squares.

Let us call a square an $n$-square if the person on that square has $n$ neighbors.

For every edge that separates two fields there are $4$ possibilities:

- the edge splits two $4$-squares
- the edge splits a $4$-square and a $3$-square
- the edge splits two $3$-squares
- the edge splits a $3$-square and a $2$-square

Find out how many of each and apply linearity of expectation.

Comment: Hi drhab, could you please show one of the possibilities, how to calculate, like say 1st one, I can think of in this way. $X_i$ will be 1 iff the 2 squares people look at a particular direction i.e. $1/4$ * $1/4$ i.e. for each number of such edges * $1/16$ would be the answer? Is this correct, if so we would not have $36$ in denominator in the answer right? Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Correct and I counted $60$ such edges. That gives term $\frac{60}{16}=\frac{135}{36}$. For the others I found the numbers $24$, $20$ and $8$.